# Tensorflow is not detecting my GPUs. What shall I do (May 2021)?

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

TF Version : 2.4.1
CUDA Version : 11.1

tf.test_is_gpu_available() -- returns --> FALSE
tf.test.is_built_with_cuda() -- returns --> TRUE

I tried to revert back TF to 2.4.0, but didn't work

I have also tried:

```
$ pip uninstall tensorflow

$ pip install tensorflow-gpu
```

But nothing seems to work, TF is just not detecting my GPUs

EDIT 1:

**Output of nvcc --version:**

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2020 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Mon_Oct_12_20:09:46_PDT_2020
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.1, V11.1.105
Build cuda_11.1.TC455_06.29190527_0
```

**Output of nvidia-smi**

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 460.73.01    Driver Version: 460.73.01    CUDA Version: 11.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce RTX 3090    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 30%   35C    P8    23W / 300W |     23MiB / 24268MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  GeForce RTX 3090    Off  | 00000000:43:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 30%   40C    P8    27W / 300W |      5MiB / 24268MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  GeForce RTX 3090    Off  | 00000000:81:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 64%   63C    P2   179W / 300W |  24043MiB / 24268MiB |     59%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      2362      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                  9MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2564      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell               12MiB |
|    1   N/A  N/A      2362      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                  4MiB |
|    2   N/A  N/A      2362      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                  4MiB |
|    2   N/A  N/A     14304      C   python3                         24035MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**While running tf.test.is_gpu_avaliable(), I get the following warning:**

```
WARNING:tensorflow:From Spell_correction.py:35: is_gpu_available (from tensorflow.python.framework.test_util) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use `tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')` instead.
2021-05-07 21:46:21.855460: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_gpu_device.cc:99] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
2021-05-07 21:46:21.856690: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:43:00.0 name: GeForce RTX 3090 computeCapability: 8.6
coreClock: 1.695GHz coreCount: 82 deviceMemorySize: 23.70GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 871.81GiB/s
2021-05-07 21:46:21.856716: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.11.0
2021-05-07 21:46:21.856735: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.11
2021-05-07 21:46:21.856747: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublasLt.so.11
2021-05-07 21:46:21.856759: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
2021-05-07 21:46:21.856771: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
2021-05-07 21:46:21.856829: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'libcusolver.so.10'; dlerror: libcusolver.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/cuda-11.1/lib64
2021-05-07 21:46:21.856846: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.11
2021-05-07 21:46:21.856856: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.8
2021-05-07 21:46:21.856863: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1757] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
2021-05-07 21:46:21.942589: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1261] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2021-05-07 21:46:21.942626: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1267]      0 
2021-05-07 21:46:21.942633: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1280] 0:   N
```

**Another Observation:**

Pytorch is detecting GPU, while TF is not.

torch.cuda.is_available() --> TRUE
tf.test.is_gpu_available() --> FALSE

Comment: what is the output of (nvcc --version)?

Comment: Please run some tensorflow code and include the output in your question, this has key information like loading of any CUDA libraries and detection of your GPU. Any other information is useless.

Comment: 2.4.1 uses CUDA 11.0.  You cannot use CUDA 11.1 as a replacement for CUDA 11.0.

Comment: @RobertCrovella,
I checked with: 
TF: 2.4.1
CUDA: 11.0
cuDNN: 8

But still the same issue as above

Comment: You mean you still see output like this: `Could not load dynamic library 'libcusolver.so.10'; dlerror: libcusolver.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/cuda-11.1/lib64`  In that case you have not set your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` correctly.

Comment: @RobertCrovella, Yes, I see they are same:

Could not load dynamic library 'libcusolver.so.10'; dlerror: libcusolver.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/cuda-11.1/lib64


`What should be my LD_LIBRARY_PATH? I don't have any idea, kindly help`

Comment: Refer to section 6 [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/archive/11.0/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#post-installation-actions)

Comment: Do you use ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Answer (score 0):

if you use ubuntu 20.04, I suggest to follow steps from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/26182#issuecomment-570815235). I recently had the same problem.

You have

```
NVIDIA-SMI 460.73.01    Driver Version: 460.73.01    CUDA Version: 11.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce RTX 3090    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 30%   35C    P8    23W / 300W |     23MiB / 24268MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A
```

try to get latest version of **NVIDIA 465** and **Cuda 11.3**. For my case nvidia-smi is as below:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 465.19.01    Driver Version: 465.19.01    CUDA Version: 11.3     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
```

What I did;

(1) I uninstalled NVIDIA and CUDA completely [see here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206283/how-can-i-uninstall-a-nvidia-driver-completely) and be careful.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge '^nvidia-.*'
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
echo 'nouveau' | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
```

(2) I downloaded [NVIDIA](https://developer.nvidia.com/nccl/nccl-download), download .run file and simply run `sudo bash NVIDIA*.run`
(3) I downloaded [cuDNN](https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn) and perform following as described [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/26182#issuecomment-570815235)

```
tar -xzvf cudnn-11.3-.*.tgz
sudo cp cuda/include/cudnn.h /usr/local/cuda/include
sudo cp cuda/lib64/libcudnn* /usr/local/cuda/lib64
sudo chmod a+r /usr/local/cuda/include/cudnn.h /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn*
```

Also check .bashrc files as well as described [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/26182#issuecomment-636398660):

```
cd ~
```

`gedit .bashrc` or `nano .bashrc`

#add this in the end :

```
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-11.3/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-11.3/lib64\${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda11.3/targets/x86_64linux\${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
```

Then, `pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.4.1`

Comment: and here is `nvcc --version`: ```nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2021 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sun_Mar_21_19:15:46_PDT_2021
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.3, V11.3.58
Build cuda_11.3.r11.3/compiler.29745058_0```